# How to make EF Core not create any indexes?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Is there a way to use EF Core in a code-first approach, but leaving creating and managing indexes completely to a db administrator?

We would like to keep migrations but just leave indexes and keys to db admin.

Is it even intended to be used that way or is it against its core principles?

Comment: The indexes EF creates by default (on PK and FK fields) are the ones I figure a DBA would always create as well. A DBA might want to add more covering indexes, unique indexes and whatever seems sensible. I wouldn't go this path *a priori*. Maybe only if a DBA has very good reasons to override these FK indexes (but I wouldn't know which reasons).

Comment: @GertArnold We have a dedicated dba and having all the indexes defined in a same way and single place by single person has a value. Its not that ef wouldnt create the same thing as dba for many things, but having indexes management scattered all over the place is not optimal from the standpoint of processes and responsibility matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Starting from EF 7**, you can edit\remove any of the built in [Model building conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#model-building-conventions)

*code sample for removing FK conventions*

```
protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
{
    configurationBuilder.Conventions.Remove(typeof(ForeignKeyIndexConvention));
}
```

In case of using lower version, you have two options:

- Explicitly remove every relationship between the models in the *OnModelCreating* method.
- Violate the [conventions for relationship discovery.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/conventions)

Comment: this sounds very promising. is there any downside in turning all indexing on ef side? (having dba manage that)

Comment: *turning off (typo)

Comment: @deezg I am not sure if there are any downsides, but I didn't find anything in the documentations that points to that direction (saying removing index conventions is not recommended).